# Is there a way to have all possible files/programs required to program and run python code on a single USB drive?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've searched around for a while but it seems there's no easy way to do it. Here's my scenario:

I'm a student in high school who enjoys fiddling with programming (specifically python, as of now), as I will soon be learning about computer science in college. I can deal with python at home just fine, since I have admin permissions on my computer. However, the computers at my school are quite restrictive (the chances of successfully downloading/installing python 3.5 on one of their computers are nearly zero). Furthermore, the school doesn't allow access to any computer settings or the command line, so changing the PATH variable is pretty much unattainable, too.

As for what I've researched, running .py files is impossible without both a full installation of python and the addition of the python directory to the PATH variable. One way to get around that would be to convert any .py file to a .exe file, which would be able to run on the school's Windows computers. However, wherever I look, anything that is said to be able to do so either requires access to the command line or doesn't support python 3.5.

Is there any program or combination of programs that, if installed on a USB drive, would allow me to program, interpret, and convert python code into an executable on any computer, whether or not that computer has python installed?

The school computers run Windows 7. My computer runs Windows 10.

Edit - There is some concern as for the school's policy, of which I have every ambition of following. However, my intention is not to bypass any of the school's safeguards - I'm fully aware of why they're there and the good that they do - but rather to be able to experiment with python and learn without having to breach any of said safeguards. If the rules say I can't tamper with the computer's system settings, so be it - but is there a way to use python without doing so?

Comment: You might want to check with your school before doing this, by the way.

Comment: You could make a Linux live usb. I used one in high school. Definitely was against computer policy, though :)

Comment: Now that you mention it, I could see how it could be sketchy with regard to the school's policy.

Comment: you could forget the usb  https://c9.io/blog/the-new-way-to-code-python/